# Webpack bundle returns 'Cannot find module' for CSS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I have an app which folders are structured like this:

```
 /app/
    |- /assets/
    |   |- /css/
    |       |- myapp.css
    |- index.html
    |- index.js
 /dist/
 /node_modules/
 .babelrc
 package.json
 webpack.config.js
```

`myapp.css` is a simple, plain css, with nothing special. Just a styling on `body` to see if it was working.
And my `webpack.config.js` file has this:

```
// In webpack.config.js
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
      {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

I have put the required css file on `index.js` like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

require('assets/css/myapp.css');

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div> Hello ReactJs</div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <HelloWorld />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

I have tried all the ways to get it loaded, adding ../ before assets word, and everythig, but I just keep receiving this error on console:
`Error: Cannot find module "assets/css/myapp.css"`

I have double check, and `css-loader` and `style-loader` are both on `/node_modules` folder.

What am I doing wrong? I am stuck on it for more than 3 hours, checking tens of tutorials, and I have done all specified. Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you tried using require('./assets/css/myapp.css'); instead of require('assets/css/myapp.css'); ?

Comment: Yep, just saw it... You are totally wright. The correct answer is yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I just needed to add `./` to the require line, like this:

`require('./assets/css/myapp.css');`

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks, @QoP